# JUnit incompability issue when using powermock and spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spock, powermock

I am trying to run tests and running into this issue warning causing tests not to be run when running a maven build

```
  Mar 07, 2023 8:57:49 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
    WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
    org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: Unsupported version of junit:junit: 4.11. Please upgrade to version 4.12 or later.
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:49)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.JUnit4VersionCheck.checkSupported(JUnit4VersionCheck.java:35)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:63)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

I figure it has to do with a compability issue with our powermock and spock here is the pom

Relavent POM.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2-groovy-2.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.9</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
          <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.9</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-common</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>powermock-reflect</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
          <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I am not sure if there is a real versioning issue but I am not sure where to continue my investigation.

Thank you

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. Besides, why are you using such old Spock and Groovy versions? Is this a legacy project? If so, think about what you changed lately. I would assume, before your changes it must have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Without you reacting to my request for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can only make an educated guess, but this

```
JUnitException: Unsupported version of junit:junit: 4.11.
Please upgrade to version 4.12 or later.
```

sounds to me like you should simply version-manage JUnit 4 for your project. Then you would no longer need to exclude anything, and probably it would just work:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then just refer to the preconfigured (managed) dependency without the version number, when declaring it:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```